# Using Regex to recognize pattern in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

*I apologize if this is a repeat question, as I know there are many about Regex on StackOverflow, but I have yet to find an answer or a level of help I need.*

> I have a string that needs to be a length of 8 where:
>
> - The first two characters are letters
> - The next five characters are numbers
> - The last character is a letter
>
> For example: "AB12345C"

I have been using the examples from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) & [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) to try and understand how to use arguments properly, but after a couple days of reading around I still can't get it to pass.

I am currently trying to use:

```
public Tuple<bool, string> stringFormatCheck(string input)
{            
     if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]\d{2}[0-9]\d{5}[a-zA-Z]$") == true)
        return Tuple.Create(true, "String is Fine");
     else
        return Tuple.Create(false, "String Format is incorrect");
}
```

Can someone show me how to use this argument properly or somewhere I can get a better understanding of the Regex Class?  Thank you.

EDIT1: The second Z in my first argument is now capitalized.

Comment: Tools like "expresso" (http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) or "the regulator" will help you analyze, build and test your regular expression, have you tried one of those?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco No, I had no idea these tools existed.  I will definitely look into those, thank you!

Comment: Your first `[a-zA-z]` is wrong.  Second Z should be uppercase.  Curious how you're testing your regex and what convinces you it's not working.

Comment: @adv12 From my understanding, Regex.IsMatch will return true if the input string matches the Regex arguments.  When I pass in a string that I assign myself, which I know fit the pattern I am trying to match, it has only returned false this far.

Comment: @Rinktacular: put your regex in Expresso -> regular expression panel: the "regex analyzer" panel will show you immediately what's wrong :)

Comment: You can also use http://www.regexr.com (online tool), as your issue is definitely in the expression rather than the use of Regex.IsMatch().

Comment: Your pattern is wrong. `^[a-zA-z]\d{2}[0-9]\d{5}[a-zA-Z]$` will match a character followed by 2 digits, another digit, followed by 5 digits and a letter.  Your first pattern `[a-zA-z]`, the second `Z` should be uppercase.  Try `^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{5}[a-zA-Z]$`

Comment: @raistlin0788 Thanks, I really could use these tools, they're very helpful.  I knew my arguments were wrong, I just couldn't understand why without seeing a specific enough example, I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right pattern is

```
"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]$"
```

with, IMHO, clear interpretation:

```
^           - string start (anchor)
[A-Za-z]{2} - 2 letters A..Z or a..z
[0-9]{5}    - 5 digits 0..9
[A-Za-z]    - letter A..Z or a..z
$           - string end (anchor)
```

And so the implementation can be

```
public Tuple<bool, string> stringFormatCheck(string input)
{            
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]$"))
        return Tuple.Create(true, "String is Fine");
    else
        return Tuple.Create(false, "String Format is incorrect");
}
```

Please, notice, that `[0-9]` is a *better choice* than `\d` since you, probably, 
don't want let, say, *Persian digits* like `"AB۰۱۲۳۴C"` ;

Comment: Thank you very much!  Just out of curiosity, are the capital A-Z required to go before the lower case a-z in the first and last arguments?

Comment: @Rinktacular: no, the order can be arbitrary `A-Za-z` as good as `a-zA-Z`

Comment: Fantastic, the code passes as expected now.  Thank you very much, I can see where I was wrong now and can properly use this in my future projects!

Comment: You're welcome! In your current pattern, just drop both `\d`

Comment: I kept seeing /d in almost every example I saw online so I was led to believe that was important to the argument I was making ha.  Your example is very clear and very helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]$`

Your regex: `^[a-zA-z]\d{2}[0-9]\d{5}[a-zA-Z]$` doesn't work for multiple reasons.  First, the second z should be capitalized.  Then, the first `\d` is trying to match a digit, so you're saying "Match any letter then two digits."  You make the same mistake with the second `\d`: you say "Match any digit (`[0-9]`) and then match 5 digits (`\d{5}`).

Comment: (Possible) counter example: `"AB۰۱۲۳۴C"` is accepted, when I'm sure it should be rejected; please notice *Persian* digits.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: That can be helped with a `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thanks.  I've replaced the `\d` with `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you, I got my answer from the other one on this question, but both of you have given me a much better understanding of Regex arguments for my use of them.